# Replace the sequence of the same item

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm making a script where the User makes a list and the same is sought in some text files and returns the results in a .txt only encounter the following problems:

The list is organized as follows on the interface:

```
Item1
item2
Item3
```

and is output as follows in the text file:

```
item1|item2|item3
```

**First problem:**

If the file from the beginning have a blank line:

```
item1

item2

item3
```

the output is with a "|" more and because the research problem:

```
item1||item2||item3
```

**Second problem:**

If the start/end have a blank line:

```
 
item1
item2
item3
```

the output is also in trouble at the time of search:

```
|item1|item2|item3|
```

**Note:** There may be several blank lines between the beginning, middle and end.

**Note 2:** The script goes inside a .hta, if necessary the code .hta will be at the end of post.

**Note 3:** The solution may be either batch, an external program or even vbs.

```
Option Explicit
    Window.resizeTo 373,610
Const csFSpec = "List.ini"
Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Sub Window_OnLoad()
  If goFS.FileExists(csFSpec) Then
     document.all.DataArea.value = goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec).ReadAll()
     document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value,"|", vbcrlf)
  Else

     self.close
  End If

  If document.all.DataArea.value =vbcrlf Then

document.all.DataArea.value =""
Else

  End If
End Sub

Sub SaveFile()
If document.all.DataArea.value = "" Then

document.all.DataArea.value =vbcrlf
  goFS.CreateTextFile(csFSpec).Write document.all.DataArea.value

     self.close
Else
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "\", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "/", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, ":", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "*", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "?", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, """", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "<", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, ">", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "|", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "&", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "!", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value,vbcrlf,"|")
  goFS.CreateTextFile(csFSpec).Write document.all.DataArea.value
     self.close
  End if
End Sub

Sub QuitEdit()

     self.close
End Sub

Sub Redefine()

document.all.DataArea.value ="Item1" & vbcrlf & "Item2" & vbcrlf & "Item3"

End Sub

Sub Clean()

document.all.DataArea.value = ""

End Sub
```

**Full Code:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>List</title>
 <HTA:Application
      Border= "thin"
      Application="/md/input"
      Scoll="NO"
      Singleinstance="Yes"
      SysMenu=NO
      Icon="%Windir%\System32\wscript.exe">
      ShowInTaskbar="Yes"
      Caption="Yes">
  <script type="text/vbscript">
Option Explicit
    Window.resizeTo 373,610
Const csFSpec = "List.ini"
Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Sub Window_OnLoad()
  If goFS.FileExists(csFSpec) Then
     document.all.DataArea.value = goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec).ReadAll()
     document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value,"|", vbcrlf)
  Else

     self.close
  End If

  If document.all.DataArea.value =vbcrlf Then

document.all.DataArea.value =""
Else

  End If
End Sub

Sub SaveFile()
If document.all.DataArea.value = "" Then

document.all.DataArea.value =vbcrlf
  goFS.CreateTextFile(csFSpec).Write document.all.DataArea.value

     self.close
Else
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "\", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "/", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, ":", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "*", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "?", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, """", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "<", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, ">", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "|", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "&", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value, "!", "_")
document.all.DataArea.value = Replace(document.all.DataArea.value,vbcrlf,"|")
  goFS.CreateTextFile(csFSpec).Write document.all.DataArea.value
     self.close
  End if
End Sub

Sub QuitEdit()

     self.close
End Sub

Sub Redefine()

document.all.DataArea.value ="Item1" & vbcrlf & "Item2" & vbcrlf & "Item3"

End Sub

Sub Clean()

document.all.DataArea.value = ""

End Sub

  </script>
 </head>
<body style="overflow:hidden" bgColor="#000080"></body>
<caption></caption><hr></hr>
<font color="#FFFFFF" Times New Roman" size="13"><center><B>List</b></center></font>
<caption></caption><hr></hr>
     <TR><td>
<input style="background-color:#F0F0F0; color: #000000; border: 2px transparent; float: left;" type="BUTTON" value="Clean" class="btn" id="btna" onclick="Clean" onmouseover="btna.style.background = '#808080'" onmouseout="btna.style.background = '#F0F0F0'">
<input style="background-color:#F0F0F0; color: #000000; border: 2px transparent; float: right;" type="BUTTON" value="Redefine" class="btn" id="btnb" onclick="Redefine" onmouseover="btnb.style.background = '#808080'" onmouseout="btnb.style.background = '#F0F0F0'">
   </TR></td>
   <Table border="3"  style="width:100%; text-align: center" BORDERCOLOR=#F0F0F0>
   <TR><td>
  <form>
<textarea name="DataArea" rows="23" cols=37></textarea>  </Table>
   <TR><td>
   <p>
 <div align="right"><input style="background-color:#F0F0F0; color: #000000; border: 2px transparent" type="BUTTON" value=" OK " class="btn" id="btnc" onclick="SaveFile" onmouseover="btnc.style.background = '#808080'" onmouseout="btnc.style.background = '#F0F0F0'">
<input style="background-color:#F0F0F0; color: #000000; border: 2px transparent" type="BUTTON" value="Cancel" class="btn" id="btnd" onclick="QuitEdit" onmouseover="btnd.style.background = '#808080'" onmouseout="btnd.style.background = '#F0F0F0'">
   </div>
  </td></TR>
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Filter at https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA!121 a set of 19 sample programs in one file for working with files. It has two sample programs, 1 for lopping off blank lines top and bottom, and another one for all blank lines. Filter has a batch file that makes calling vbs scripts easy.

**TrimLine**

```
filter trimline {top|end|both}
filter tl {t|e|b}
```

Trims blank lines from top and bottom of files.

```
top - removes blank lines from top of file.
end - removes blank lines from end of file.
both - removes blank lines from top and end of file.
```

**Example**

Fixes win.ini, not that it needs fixing, and sends it to the screen

```
filter trimline both < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

**Script**

```
Sub TrimLines
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

    If LCase(Arg(1)) = "top" or LCase(Arg(1)) = "t" then 
        Flags = 0
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
            If Line <> "" then Flags = 1
            If Flags = 1 then outp.writeline Line
        Loop
    ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "e" or LCase(Arg(1)) = "end" then
        PendingLines = ""
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
            If Line <> "" then 
                outp.writeline PendingLines & Line
                PendingLines = ""
            Else
                PendingLines=PendingLines & vbcrlf
            End If
        Loop
    ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "b" or LCase(Arg(1)) = "both" then
        Flags = 0
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
            If Line <> "" then Flags = 1
            If Flags = 1 then 
                If Line <> "" then 
                    outp.writeline PendingLines & Line
                    PendingLines = ""
                Else
                    PendingLines=PendingLines & vbcrlf
                End If
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

**BlankLine**

```
filter blankline {e|a}
```

Trims all empty and/or blank lines from a file.

```
e - removes blank lines from a file.
a - removes blank lines and lines only composed of space or tab from a file.
```

Example

Fixes win.ini, not that it needs fixing, and sends it to the screen

```
filter blankline a < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

**Script**

```
Sub BlankLine
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    Set RegEx = New RegExp
    RegEx.Pattern = "^\s+$"
        If LCase(Arg(1)) = "e" then
            Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
                Line=Inp.ReadLine
                If Len(Line) <> 0 Then
                    OutP.WriteLine Line
                End If
            Loop
        ElseIf Lcase(Arg(1)) = "a" then
            Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
                Line=Inp.ReadLine
                If Len(Line) <> 0 Then
                    If RegEx.Test(Line) = False then
                        OutP.WriteLine Line
                    End If
                End If
            Loop
        End If
End Sub
```

Also you could use VBS replace command.

```
A = Replace("blah||blah", "||", "|")
```